# Is there a timing for regeneration

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Charging Troll](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCharging%20Troll%5d) has the ability

> G: Regenerate Charging Troll

If you cast [Lava Coil](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLava%20Coil%5d), on it and later it receives lethal damage does it regenerate or get exiled?  Does it matter when it was regenerated vs when lava coil was cast on it?